# MySQL full text search result problem

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have this query that does not return any results:

```
SELECT
    MATCH (e.firstname, e.lastname, e.tc_identity) AGAINST ('Baha') AS Score
    , e.*
FROM
    employees AS e
WHERE
    MATCH (e.firstname, e.lastname, e.tc_identity) AGAINST ('Baha' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY `Score` DESC;
```

`firstname`, `lastname` and `tc_identity` are of type `varchar`.

I have data in `firstname` like 'Bahadir', 'Bahadır', etc...

When I try to match against 'Baha', I get no results.

When I try to match against 'Bahadir' or 'Bahadır', I get no results.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is looking for the token = 'Baha'. You need a wildcard search for 'Baha*'.

Please try the following

```
SELECT
MATCH (`e`.`firstname`, `e`.`lastname`, `e`.`tc_identity`) AGAINST ('Baha*') AS `Score`,
`e`.*

FROM
`employees` AS `e`

WHERE
MATCH (`e`.`firstname`, `e`.`lastname`, `e`.`tc_identity`) AGAINST ('Baha*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

ORDER BY `Score` DESC
```

Comment: Results return, but score looks 0 ?